# MongoDB - Update parent using child

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document structure like this : (but with many markers and forms)

```
{
  markers : [
    {
      id : 1,
      updateDate : 1538051924574,
      forms : [
        {
          id : 2,
          sent : false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I wanted to update forms.sent to true, so I made this query :

```
updateOne({
}, {
  $set: {
    "markers.$[].forms.$[b].sent": true
  }
}, {
  arrayFilters: [
    {"b.id": "2"}
  ]
})
```

Everything is working as intended, but now I would like to update markers.udpateDate for every forms.sent updated. But I don't have access to marker.id, I can only use form.id.

My question is, can I update parent attribute using only child accessor ?

I already tried something like this :

```
updateOne({
}, {
  $set: {
    "markers.$[].forms.$[b].sent": true,
    "markers.$[].updateDate": Date.now()
  }
}, {
  arrayFilters: [
    {"b.id": "2"}
  ]
})
```

But as I would think, it does update every markers in the array..

If anyone has any idea,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another placeholder for parent, and duplicate you arrayFiter with this new placeholder :

```
db['01'].updateOne({
}, {
  $set: {
    "markers.$[].forms.$[b].sent": true,
    "markers.$[dateUp].updateDate": Date.now()  <=
  }
}, {
  arrayFilters: [
    {"b.id": 2},  
    {"dateUp.forms.id":2}  <=
  ]
})
```

Note : You used string value in your arrayFilters, but according to your schema it must be a number.